# Expiration of a Delta ecredit following a changed date

Tags: delta-air-lines

I am considering changing my Delta ticket from a flight this June to one later this year. The new price will be less than the old so I will be offered E-credits I imagine. Now I believe the expiration of the Ecredits is 12 months? But the original tickets were issued over 12 months ago (we plan ahead!) so surely that can’t mean 12 months expiration from that date! 
Thanks

Comment: Delta won't refund even a refundable ticket more than a year after the ticket was issued. What makes you think they'll give you eCredits at all?

Comment: Sorry for the necro but I'm really curious how you even got tickets issued more than 12 months beforehand? As far as I know most airlines won't sell tickets more than 11 months, 330 days, or 331 days in advance.